# When I change input type from text to email, letters overlap (form using only css and html)

Tags: html, css, forms, web-deployment

When I change input type from text to email in my contact form - letters overlap, but only when your input is not email.I'm stuck.

It has to be html and css only.  I'm new to web dev so please be gentle :)

[PrtSc from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmt6.png)

[Webpage contact form with input type="text"](https://kpietrzyk.github.io/Contact-Form-v1-/)

[Github repo with form](https://github.com/kpietrzyk/Contact-Form-v1-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is this bunch of styles.

```
.box input:focus ~ label,
.box textarea:focus ~ label,
.box input:valid ~ label,
.box textarea:valid ~ label
{
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: #911b64;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This says to move the `label` upward when you try to type into the input field and it says there only if the value is `valid`. When you change the `type="text"` to `type="email"`, it expects the input to be a valid email address.

So the issue you talked about is only appearing when you input invalid email address. Try a valid email address, something in this format `abc@aba.ab`.

However, if you want the `label` to stay up even you insert invalid email address after you changed the `type="text"` to `type="email"`. Try this code.

```
.box input:focus ~ label,
.box textarea:focus ~ label,
.box textarea:valid ~ label
{
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: #911b64;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: .box input:focus ~ label,
.box textarea:focus ~ label,
.box textarea:valid ~ label
{
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: #911b64;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

This doesn't work :/

Comment: seems like the only way to avoid this issue is to input the correct format email address